# Lenguaje R , seleccionar columnas por su nombre al igual que loc en Python

Tags: r, dplyr

Querría saber si hay un atajo para seleccionar columnas en R,en un dataframe, por su nombre como hace el método `loc` de Python. Por ejemplo

Supongamos que tenemos un dataframe de 5 columnas cuyo nombres sean columna 1, columna 2 ... columna5 y quiero seleccionar desde la columna 2 hasta la 5 por su nombre.
He probado `name_df[,'columna1':'columna2']`, pero no funciona.

---

Vale, nada ya lo he encontrado, se hace con la función select:
select(name_df, columna1:columna5)

Answer (score 0):

No, con R base no es posible hacer lo que buscas, pero eventualmente si podrías generar una secuencia numérica conociendo la posición de la primera y última columna:

```
name_df[,2:5]
```

Lo que buscas requiere de una inteligencia que no es parte del lenguaje, pero si de ciertos paquetes comno `dplyr`, con el que si puedes hacerlo:

```
library(dplyr)
name_df %>% 
  select(columna2:columna5)
```

Nota: En realidad, ahora que lo pienso mejor, si es posible con R base, pero usando `subset()` y nuevamente, la interpretación de `columna2:columna5` como una secuencia de nombres, lo hace `subset` pero no forma parte de la indexación estándar de R:

```
subset(name_df, select = columna2:columna5)
```

Answer (score 0):

Agrego un Ejemplo Reproducible para que vean las posibilidades de select admite columnas con espacios agregandole backticks ``:

```
df = tibble( 
  `Student` = c("A","B","C","D","E"),
  `GPA x1` = c(3.2, 2.7, 2.5, 3.4, 2.2),
  `Age x2` = c(22, 27, 24, 28, 23),
  `State board score y` = c(550,570,525,670,490)
)

df %>%
  select(`GPA x1`:`Age x2`)
# A tibble: 5 x 2
  `GPA x1` `Age x2`
     <dbl>    <dbl>
1      3.2       22
2      2.7       27
3      2.5       24
4      3.4       28
5      2.2       23
```